# Is this hint for exercise 9(b) on p.52 in section 7 in chapter 1 in "Topology 2nd Edition" by James R. Munkres right?

Tags: functions, solution-verification, recurrence-relations

I am reading "Topology 2nd Edition" by James R. Munkres.
I am trying to solve Exercise 9(b) on p.52 in section 7 in chapter 1.
Is the following hint right?
I think $f$ doesn't satisfy (*).
$f(3)\neq h(3)=h(4)^2-h(2)^2=f(4)^2-f(2)^2.$

$g(1)=h(1)$.
$g(2)=h(2)$.
$g(3)=-h(3)$.
$g(n)=\sqrt{g(n-1)+[g(n-2)]^2}$ for $n\geq 4$.
By the principle of recursive definition, there exists a function $g:\mathbb{Z}_{+}\to\mathbb{R}$ satisfying the above formula.
Obviously, this $g$ satisfies (*).
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hint is poorly stated.

The reformulation of part (a) is $h(n+1) = \sqrt{h(n) + [h(n-1)]^2}$, as I assume you've already found.

But for $f$ the idea is that
$$f(3) = -\sqrt{f(2) + [f(1)]^2} = -\sqrt 3\\f(n+1) = \sqrt{f(n) + [f(n-1)]^2}, \quad n \ge 3$$

Unfortunately, he tried to abbreviate this too much, and it didn't come out right.

Quite frankly, I'm not sure why he bothered with a hint. It seems obvious that the way to come up with other solutions to (*) is to take the opposite square root somewhere down the line.

Comment: Paul Sinclair, Thank you very much for your answer!